# Tag editor that can store id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Looking for tag editor autocomplete plug-in that can store tag ids in hidden fields.

Required functionality:

- Show labels, store ids
- Multiple tags
- Remote datasource via ajax
- On tag click events

Tried [tag-it](http://aehlke.github.com/tag-it/) but was unable to make it store ids.

Comment: A little jquery makes this easy to write on your own. I have one I use at work and its around 30 lines.

Comment: @Syddraf yes i can write my own but would like to use stable ones that were tested and fixed by many people :) It's a little bit strange for me the such famous tag-it doesnt have that in-demant feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one. It has all you need:

http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/

Features

- Intuitive UI for selecting multiple items from a large list
- Easy to skin/style purely in css, no images required
- Supports any backend which can generate JSON, including PHP, Rails, Django, ASP.net
- Smooth animations when results load
- Select, delete and navigate items using the mouse or keyboard
- Client-side result caching to reduce server load
- Crossdomain support via JSONP
- Callbacks when items are added or removed from the list
- Preprocess results from the server with the onResult callback
- Programatically add, remove, clear and get tokens
- Customize the output format of the results and tokens